# How to enable Database search & autocomplete live search?

Tags: 8, search, ajax

Found a great article of how to enable live search on drupal 7 http://www.stevepolitodesign.com/blog/create-live-search-results-search-you-type-drupal

But seems all modules are not yet available for drupal 8. Can anyone show some  light on this please of how a similar thing can be done on drupal 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I get this right, but you can just use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete where you get live autocompletion for your search terms.

Comment: Good catch! I'm guilty as I didn't check anything after reading that OP said that the modules aren't available for D8 :D

Comment: This module is actually more complete for the purpose than the one I found. AIO.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to write a custom module for this.

Here's the basic idea:

- You should decide with which search mechanism you want this to work. For the sake of simplicity, I'll use the core Search module as an example.
- Declare a new autocomplete field with your custom callback path; it *might* work if you just alter the search field type, turn it into autocomplete and add your custom callback path. I'm not sure if this will work in D8 though.
- Whenever user changes the input, your module should query the database and see if there are any matching keywords stored in the search module. You can include any additional logic here, e.g. limit the search to nodes only, give some criteria higher visibility, exclude some keywords, etc.
- Return back the similar keywords so user can choose some of them.
- When search is submitted, display search results from core search module. If it's possible, the best would be to alter the search input field, so you don't have to much else to handle form submission, etc.

I didn't check much, but this should get you going. For more info on D8 form API, check [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8) out. If you need to see how is this done in the core, check out the code for referencing the users (e.g. author field in node forms).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But i was looking for some readymade solution. Seems Matthias directed me to the one I'm looking for. However your suggestion might be helpful for someone. Thumbs up

Comment: Sure; Matthias' solution is the proper answer - I didn't even check if there are any D8 modules for this, I just assumed there aren't any :D